# Connecting android to sql database using php error

Tags: php, android

i have been following this tutorial from androidhive which gives you the source code. i have downloaded and installed the wamp server and it seems fine. when i run the code the application opens but when it comes to send data it takes long and then eventually forces me to close the application. i have tryed everything i can think of including installing and unistalling everything but i cant figure out what is wrong. there are no errors in the code. here is the log cat which i dont understand. please help its for my dissertation

```
02-20 16:54:58.901: E/JSON Parser(277): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><TITLE>404 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-20 16:54:58.901: W/dalvikvm(277): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:99)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:1)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-20 16:54:58.940: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  ... 4 more
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277): Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f04ae8 that was originally added here
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f04ae8 that was originally added here
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:76)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:56)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-20 16:55:00.051: E/WindowManager(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You're building an app for your dissertation? So most likely some sort of computer science. Why for the love of Pete would you use a technology you obviously don't know? That seems very illogical.

Comment: because im useless at everything anyway. thanks for your help

Comment: Seems like you should be proficient at whatever you're about to get a degree in... but I digress. The problem is in "doInBackground()". You would need to post the relevant PHP code for someone to be able to help.